# Calculate the mean of column A based on a 2 minute time window in Datetime Column

Tags: python

I want to take the average power computed for 2 minute windows based on my time column t which is set as index.

```
            power   cadence
t       
00:00:00    171.0   74.0
00:00:01    229.0   71.0
00:00:02    229.0   71.0
00:00:03    229.0   71.0
00:00:04    328.0   70.0
...         ...     ...
01:06:40    0.0     0.0
01:06:41    0.0     0.0
01:06:42    0.0     0.0
01:06:43    0.0     0.0
01:06:44    0.0     0.0
```

I tried this so far:
pwr["average"] = pwr["power"].rolling(120).mean()

which computes the rolling average across a 2 minute window.

Any suggestions on how I can get the average power and not the rolling average for the given time window? This would reduce the data points in the output which I want.

Comment: try `pwr['power'].resample('2min').mean()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reduce the data to 2 minute windows, the frequency of the average data would switch to 2 minutes instead of 1 second.

You can use resample to get the averages.

Here is a small example

```py
power = np.random.rand(600)
cadence = np.random.rand(600)
t = np.arange(600)
timestamps = [datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(x)) for x in t]
pwr = pd.DataFrame(zip(power, cadence), index=timeseries, columns={'power', 'cadence'})
pwr.resample('2min').mean()
```

From the original dataframe

```
                   power   cadence
0 days 00:00:00  0.830027  0.184573
0 days 00:00:01  0.915376  0.837455
0 days 00:00:02  0.699225  0.136516
0 days 00:00:03  0.692789  0.301164
0 days 00:00:04  0.890294  0.954707
...                   ...       ...
0 days 00:09:55  0.419489  0.689846
0 days 00:09:56  0.553243  0.515789
0 days 00:09:57  0.361660  0.643095
0 days 00:09:58  0.940207  0.838618
0 days 00:09:59  0.594426  0.108080

[600 rows x 2 columns]
```

This would produce the following 2 minute data:

```
                   power   cadence
0 days 00:00:00  0.530908  0.514137
0 days 00:02:00  0.502127  0.539745
0 days 00:04:00  0.488102  0.499505
0 days 00:06:00  0.508043  0.509993
0 days 00:08:00  0.528632  0.478071
```

If you would like to have `datetime.time` values as index instead of TimeDeltaIndex, you could generate a list of time objects out of the index

```py
pwr2min = pwr.resample('2min').mean()
pwr2min["t"] = pwr2min.index.components.apply(
    lambda x: datetime.time(
        hour=x["hours"], 
        minute=x["minutes"], 
        second=x["seconds"]),
    axis=1,
).values
pwr2min.set_index('t', inplace=True)
```

This would make `pwr2min` look like this:

```
            power   cadence
t                           
00:00:00  0.530908  0.514137
00:02:00  0.502127  0.539745
00:04:00  0.488102  0.499505
00:06:00  0.508043  0.509993
00:08:00  0.528632  0.478071
```

**Update**

Suppose your original dataframe had `HH:MM:SS` strings as index.

```
             power   cadence
t                           
00:00:00  0.830027  0.184573
00:00:01  0.915376  0.837455
00:00:02  0.699225  0.136516
00:00:03  0.692789  0.301164
00:00:04  0.890294  0.954707
```

To convert to `timedelta` you could do using `pd.to_timedelta()`

```py
rawpwr = pd.read_excel('pwr.xlsx')
rawpwr.set_index('t', inplace=True)
rawpwr.index = pd.to_timedelta(rawpwr.index)
```

This would produce a dataframe with TimedeltaIndex where resample could be applied.

```
                    power   cadence
t                                  
0 days 00:00:00  0.830027  0.184573
0 days 00:00:01  0.915376  0.837455
0 days 00:00:02  0.699225  0.136516
0 days 00:00:03  0.692789  0.301164
0 days 00:00:04  0.890294  0.954707
```

Finally if you somehow got a dataframe `timepwr` with `datetime.time` as index, then the following two step routine should work.

```py
timepwr.index = pd.to_timedelta(
    [
        datetime.timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
        for t in timepwr.index
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast fix. I'm using a different excel import file now with a different time format [h]:mm:ss so without the date, giving me a new error which I haven't figured out yet :
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Reformatting like this, didn't work:
pwr["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(pwr["datetime"], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time

Comment: @Hansson updated the post with some options to get TimedeltaIndex from 'HH:MM:SS' strings or `datetime.time` objects.